# spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes does not work when multiLine is set to true

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I read a dataframe using spark, it defaults to one partition . 
Once if I set the property 
("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes","1000") , it partitions correctly according to the bytes.

But If I give multiline as true, it does not seem to work.

Test.csv is about 50KB

```
spark.sqlcontext.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes" , "1000")
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("quote" , "\"").option("escape", "\"").load("/home/Test.csv")
scala> df.rdd.getNumPartitions
res1: Int = 50
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("quote" , "\"").option("escape", "\"").option("multiLine" , "true").load("/home/Test.csv")
scala> df.rdd.getNumPartitions
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: @thebluephantom Actually wanted to partition the file while handling multiline cases , which I somehow did not get the answer for it ! Anyways .. Cheers! :)

Comment: But I can give you no answer as it is a limitation of multiline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html):

> This configuration is effective only when using file-based sources such as Parquet, JSON and ORC.

Answer (score 1):

I infer that multiline implies logically speaking, non-splittable input and hence the file is assigned to a single Executor which results in a single partition.

Comment: that means the entire file is loaded into single Executor memory ? What if the CSV file is too big and cant  fit into executor memory ?